# How to get correct frame size of NavigationController in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get correct content frame size which considered the navigationbar's height size. 
But if output frame size using NSLog in willRotateTo~ method, shows earlier frame size. 
However it shows correct frame size in didRotateFrom~ method. 
How to get the frame size like didRotateFrom~ 's size in willRotateTo~ method?

Following is AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    ViewController *rootView = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView] autorelease];

    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView] autorelease];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And next is ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"willRotate size is width : %f  height : %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    NSLog(@"didRotate size is width : %f  height : %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Following is result when rotated to landscape.

[image]

```
/Users/nice7285/Library/Caches/appCode10/DerivedData/testView-d007adbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testView.app/testView
Simulator session started with process 3896
2012-10-11 04:28:59.719 testView[3896:11303] willRotate size is width : 320.000000  height : 416.000000
2012-10-11 04:29:00.025 testView[3896:11303] didRotate size is width : 480.000000  height : 268.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `self.view.frame` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is giving you the dimensions before rotation is because the view has not been rotated yet, so the the frame has not been changed yet. The only thing you can know at that point is what orientation you are rotating to. If you want the new dimensions in that function you'll have to hardcode them in yourself. You shouldn't need to do this though as `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` should be able to do everything you want.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below. The above solution isn't aesthetically pleasing. Also, hardcoding dimension pts is a no-no since its harder to manage since different devices have different dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer doesn't really solve the problem you're faced with. If you perform your UI changes in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation, the UI changes happen AFTER the screen has performed its rotation animation. This ends up looking really ugly and sudden.

You should use willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation, which is called after the rotation has happened, bounds have been recalculated, and allows you to setup your UI controls for the animation. This will let you perform a smooth transition from one orientation to another.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. I first used **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** and seemed work fine. But lie @nenchev it showed some ugly transforming animation. And I used **willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation** now it's working like charm. Thanks.

Comment: very nice answer, I was looking for this methods a long ago :)